# Cannot retrieve Selected option value

Tags: jquery

I can able to get the selected option value in onchange event. But, when clicking the ok button in the same page , I can't get the value selected. Please help me..

Code is as follows:

```
<select  id ="userstoassign">
<option value="s1">S1</option>
<option value="s2" selected="selected">S2</option>
<option value="s3">S3</option>
</select>
<input type="button" name="ok" id="ok" value="ok"/>

$("#ok").live('click', function(){
       var username= $("#userstoassign option:selected").val();
       alert(username);

    });
```

Note: In onchange event, I can get the selected value. Temp fix is I'm getting that value in onchange event in a variable and will use it in onclick event. Even in onchange event I'm getting default value if I use the code "$("#userstoassign option:selected").val();"

```
    $('#userstoassign').live('change',function(){                    selectedUser=this.value;
alert(selectedUser);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason being I'm including my jsp in another jsp which is creating this issue. But, if I create select box dynamically, then I'm not getting that issue. But, stil couldn't find why this bug is occuring.

```
<%@ include file="Common.jsp" %>
```

In this common.jsp, I'm using select box, which is creating this issue. I removed select box from this jsp and creating it dynamically in the js.

Answer (score 1):

```
var username= $("#userstoassign option:selected").val();
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/qsYwr/1/

Comment: By default it will return the first value only. You need to have selected="selected" to the correct option for it return the value. Demo attached.

Comment: Does ur option have selected="selected" ? did you check the demo ? can you put ur case in jsfiddle, might help to debug.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KQxxx/ this works. if you click ok you get the selected element value.

Comment: I don't know wat's happening. That code is working fine. But, for me if I try in my code, I'm getting the default value still. :-( So strange

Comment: hmm .. check through firebug if the selected tag is assigned to the option. you can compare the script with demo and try to seperate the code.

Comment: add your code to jsfiddle as is in page. Might help to debug.

Answer (score 1):

simple:

```
var username=  $("#userstoassign").val();
```

Comment: it returns selected option value, by default first option is always selected, do it on change - you will see the new value will be returned

Comment: you should look at the example I've provided, first time the current selected value is alerted, then you can change selection and click on the 'get selected value' button, is this what you need?

Comment: S.. I tried. But, surprisingly it is not workign in my code. In onchange event, "this.value" is working. There also "var username=  $("#userstoassign").val();"  is not working. Giving default value always

Comment: look at http://jsbin.com/adahat/2/edit#javascript,htmll your code is working, click on the render button

Comment: well, can you post more of your code? or link to your demo page